# Angular, RxJs - dynamic new observable with user reaction as resolve

Tags: angular, rxjs

We are creating a messenger module, what needs to be RxJs based and need to emit a value based on user reaction to another component.

I've tried with of(), passing existing BehaviorSubject, but none of them was worked as expected. The functionality should be like a simple promise what the user could resolve.

Some protocode to show the idea:

```
MessageService {
  message = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

  addMessage(message) {
    this.message.next(message);
    return new Subject();
  }

  userClick(boolean) {
  // clicked on Ok or Cancel
  // We want to send that value to the subscription on addMessage
  }

}

AnotherService {
  ....
  this.messageService.addMessage('Are you sure?')
      .subscribe(boolean => console.log(boolean));
  ....
}
```

So when the user click on the Ok or Cancel button in what handled in the MessageService, the subscription at the AnotherService should receive the answer.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. But I see you have data traveling between two classes, so it might make sense to involve a third class to hold states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform that you need somewhere to have an Observable created as well as method which will pass `true/false` for example.

This could be done by

```
requestUser(): Observable<boolean> {
// do some actions

return new Observable(observer => {
  // react here on what user does
  observer.next(true);
})
}
```

what will cause the subscriber to get true/false on `subscribe`.